# SQL to find - how many customers purchased multiple times on what days in a given date range - Cohort analysis

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

**I Have just one table (transaction_table) with data as following -**

| User_id | Order_dt | Order_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 2020-01-03 | 1 |
| a1 | 2020-01-03 | 2 |
| b1 | 2020-01-03 | 1 |
| c1 | 2020-01-03 | 1 |
| d1 | 2020-01-03 | 1 |
| e1 | 2020-01-03 | 1 |
| f1 | 2020-01-03 | 1 |
| a11 | 2020-01-04 | 1 |
| b11 | 2020-01-04 | 1 |
| c11 | 2020-01-04 | 1 |
| c11 | 2020-01-04 | 2 |
| b11 | 2020-01-04 | 1 |
| a1 | 2020-01-04 | 1 |
| a | 2020-01-05 | 1 |
| b | 2020-01-05 | 1 |
| c | 2020-01-05 | 1 |
| c | 2020-01-05 | 2 |
| d | 2020-01-05 | 1 |
| c1 | 2020-01-05 | 1 |
| b11 | 2020-01-05 | 1 |
| a11 | 2020-01-05 | 1 |
| .... | .................. | .. |

---

I am  trying to find the repeated customers for the rest of the week (customer retention cohort analysis)

**Basically, out of total unique purchasers per day, How many unique customers are returning on each day of the week for a given date range - WHERE (Order_dt BETWEEN '2020-01-03' AND '2020-01-09')**

I am trying to get to an output like the following -

| Order_dt | UniqueCust_perDay | On_day+1 | On_day+2 | On_day+3 | On_day+4 | On_day+5 | On_day+6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-03 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 0 | .. | .. | .. |
| 2020-01-04 | 3 | 2 | 0 | .. | .. | .. | NULL |
| 2020-01-05 | 4 | 0 | .. | .. | .. | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-01-06 | .. | .. | .. | .. | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-01-07 | .. | .. | .. | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-01-08 | .. | .. | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2020-01-09 | .. | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

---

**So far, my code is not giving me the output plus i am super confused on self joining the table to get unique values for consecutive days.**

My code -

```
SELECT date(v.order_dt) as Order_Date,
COUNT(CASE when v.order_dt = vv.minva then v.user_uuid end) as net_new_Purchasers,
(COUNT(DISTINCT v.user_id) - COUNT(CASE WHEN v.order_dt = vv.minva THEN v.user_id END)
) as repeated_purchasers,
COUNT(DISTINCT v.user_id) as unique_purchasers,
COUNT(DISTINCT v.order_id) as unique_orders,
FROM transaction_table v
JOIN
(SELECT user_id, min(order_dt) AS minva
FROM transaction_table t
GROUP BY user_id
) vv
ON v.user_uuid = vv.user_uuid
WHERE
(v.order_date BETWEEN '2020-01-03' AND '2020-01-09')
GROUP BY
date(v.order_date)
```

---

**I would really be super grateful for any help my way to help solve my confusion, Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . If you want this for every day, then one method is a self join and aggregation:

```
select du.order_dt, count(distinct du.user_id) as on_day,
       count(distinct case when du2.order_dt = du.order_dt + interval '1' day then du2.user_id) as day_1,
       count(distinct case when du2.order_dt = du.order_dt + interval '2' day then du2.user_id) as day_2,
       . . .
from (select distinct user_id, order_dt
      from transaction_table t
     ) du left join
     (select distinct user_id, order_dt
      from transaction_table t
     ) du2
     on du2.user_id = du.user_id and du2.order_dt > du.order_dt
group by du.user_id
```

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff - i see that in line 6 there is a ')' for 'du' , a '(' has not been opened before line 6, am i missing something ? Please help me out! Thank you very much for showing me some direction on aggregating this. Can i also specify a date range in 'Where' condition?

Comment: @PavithraG . . . I must've accidentally deleted a line or two.  In any case, I added back in the logic that I think I intended.

Comment: how does this code change if i need to insert a CASE statement to fetch a region column from another table ? EX- CASE WHEN d.country_id IN (235,40) THEN 'NA' ELSE 'INTL' END AS economic_area,
    d.category as category

Comment: @PavithraG . . . That would be a different question and should be asked as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a full working example, tested on sql server. *(I do not have access to Hive).*

```
select o.order_dt,min(UniqueCust_perDay) UniqueCust_perDay, 
max( case when o2.order_dt = ( dateadd(day,1,o.order_dt)) then cnt end) as "On_day+1" ,
 max( case when o2.order_dt = ( dateadd(day,2,o.order_dt)) then cnt end) as "On_day+2",
 max( case when o2.order_dt = ( dateadd(day,3,o.order_dt)) then cnt end) as "On_day+3",
 max( case when o2.order_dt = ( dateadd(day,4,o.order_dt)) then cnt end) as "On_day+4",
 max( case when o2.order_dt = ( dateadd(day,5,o.order_dt)) then cnt end) as "On_day+5",
 max( case when o2.order_dt = ( dateadd(day,6,o.order_dt)) then cnt end) as "On_day+6"
from
(select o.order_dt,count (distinct o.user_id)  UniqueCust_perDay
from transaction_table o
group by o.order_dt) o ,
(
select du.order_dt,count(distinct du.user_id) cnt
from  
(select distinct order_dt, user_id
from transaction_table
) du,
(select distinct order_dt, user_id
from transaction_table
) du2
where 
    du.order_dt >  du2.order_dt
and du.user_id = du2.user_id
group by du.order_dt) o2
where o.order_dt between '2020-01-03' AND '2020-01-09'  
group by  o.order_dt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, currently running it on hive. I have a quick question - say i have a additional join and need to filter data for a particular date range, EX: WHERE (Order_dt BETWEEN '2020-01-03' AND '2020-01-09') - Can i do this after line 10?

Comment: SQL Error [40000] [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid table alias or column reference 'day': (possible column names are: o.order_date, o.uniquecust_perday, o2.order_date, o2.cnt) - getting this error

Comment: I added the where clause to the code for dates. Regarding the error, you may need to make minor changes to the query to account for syntax differences on HIVE platform. For example - the function to add days to date could be different.

Comment: Hi @mountainX - for some reason - the values for "on_day+1" and the rest of them gives a higher value. How do i the non repeated values for this? for some reason "cnt" is giving higher values. Am i missing something? Requesting your guidance on this. the "uniqueCust_perDay is perfect - i need the returning customers from the unique cust of order_date='2020-01-03' for the rest of the days until 2020-01-09

Comment: hi @mountainX - while your code is perfect - it doesnt pass all the test cases of counting the repeated customers on all the consecutive days for 2020-01-03 and so on... My question is -> on 2020-01-03, out of 6 unique customers - how many have returned/ purchased on each of the week up to 2020-01-09.

Comment: @PavithraG In the example data that you provided, this is the list of customers who returned along with their return date. The query displays the same counts for each date . That is, Out of 6 unique customers, 4 returned..                                     
 order_dt   user_id visit_count
---------- ------- -----------
2020-01-04     a1       1
2020-01-05     a11     1
2020-01-05     b11     1
2020-01-05 c1       1